# Overwrite a Backup

Tags: sqlsitemapprovider

I need to set up a job to create backup everyday. I also need to overwrite an existing backup.
Can somebody please help me with it.

Thanks,

Comment: You wanted to go to: http://serverfault.com/

And when you go and ask there...please describe your problem a bit more. One tag and some vague description about some backup job is not enough for anyone to help you.

Comment: Sorry Guys. Actuall this is for SQL jOb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `mysqldump`.

```
mysqldump db_name tbl_name > backupfile.sql
```

will dump the a db / table and overwrite backupfile.sql if it exists.

Use `rsync` or `scp` to copy it to another host if needed.

Comment: Thank you but I did not really get it. Can you please let me know 
 how is this mysqldump created.